# How to change default program for http(s):// links in Xubuntu/XFCE

Tags: configuration, browser, mime-type, xdg-open

I am using XFCE on Xubuntu. I want my default browser to be Chromium.

In **Settings Manager > Preferred Applications** web browser is set to Chromium.

In gconf-editor: `/desktop/gnome/url-handlers/http` and `/desktop/gnome/url-handlers/https` `command` key is set to `exo-open --launch WebBrowser %s`. `exo-open --launch WebBrowser https://google.com` launches Chromium.

```
note:~$ xdg-mime query default x-scheme-handler/http
chromium.desktop
note:~$ xdg-mime query default x-scheme-handler/https
chromium.desktop
```

But programs open http(s) links with Firefox. For example, `xdg-open https://google.com` launches Firefox.

How can I fix it?

**UPD1**: Chromium settings: "Chromium cannot determine or set the default browser."

Comment: How about if you go to Chromium's settings and make it the default browser?

Comment: what about `update-alternatives --config x-www-browser` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change default browser using `update-alternatives --config x-www-browser`:

```
$ update-alternatives --config x-www-browser

There are 2 choices for the alternative link group x-www-browser \
(providing /usr/bin/x-www-browser).

  Selection    Path                Priority        Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/firefox         50        auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/chromium        10       manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

The current choice has a `*`. Just press the number of the browser you want to use. In this example I would type `1` to make Chromium the default browser.

Comment: In my case, ubuntu 18.04, xfce 4.12, run this does not work, need to edit `~/.config/mimeapps.list` on field `x-scheme-handler/http=chromium-browser.desktop
x-scheme-handler/https=chromium-browser.desktop`

Comment: @Tiana987642 thanks! I suggest posting a new answer with this useful information