# What determines my default browser?

Tags: browser

If I run Beamer, using the `\href` command, e.g.,

```
 \documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\href{http://www.people-press.org/2014/06/12/section-1-growing-ideological-consistency/\#interactive}{\beamergotobutton{Pew Research Center 2014}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

when I click on the link in the resulting .pdf file, the browser that opens is for some reason `opera`.

Also, when I use video conferencing software, at some point the browser that gets opened is `opera`.

So, presumably, Opera has wormed its way into some config file, in spite
of the fact that I use `chrome` almost all of the time. Could somebody,
please, explain how that happens?

Comment: try `update-alternatives --config x-www-browser` [like here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/805969/how-to-change-default-program-for-https-links-in-xubuntu-xfce/806126#806126)

Comment: Tjhanks!    This fixed the problem,   wierd that the setting here was different from the setting in System-settings->Details

Comment: yeah, I don't know why that's the ticket either, glad you fixed it :)

Answer (score 2):

Go to `System Settings...`, then click on the `Detail` icon, then select `Default Applications`, like so:

[image]

Cheers, Al

Comment: For some reason this didnt help, Web dropdown was already set to chromium