# how to change default browser via terminal/update-alternatives?

Tags: 16.04, default-programs

My question is not specific to just the web browser but other things like mail/calender/opening PDF/zip/other file extensions.

So how can I change default browser using terminal? I've tried these 2 commands and

```
update-alternatives --set gnome-www-browser /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable
update-alternatives --set x-www-browser /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable
```

According to

```
update-alternatives --get-selections | grep browser
```

Google Chrome is supposedly my default browser.

[image]

But when I go to System Settings, Firefox is listed as the default.

[image]

When I double-click a simple HTML I created using vi, the file opens up in Firefox. I restarted Ubuntu but I get the same behavior.

so what am I doing wrong? Thank you.

**edit1:** I've also tried update-alternatives --config gnome-www-browser/x-ww-browser. no effect

[image]

**edit2:** According to update-alternatives, firefox is not assigned to anything!

[image]

Comment: See [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/805969/how-to-change-default-program-for-https-links-in-xubuntu-xfce/806126#806126) for correct usage?

Comment: @Zanna I've edited the original post. I forgot to say I've also tried that

Comment: Please, provide text outputs rather than screenshots. It helps finding the question and improves formatting. Thanks

Comment: If you run `x-www-browser google.com` it should open in whatever you set with `update-alternatives`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That settings cannot be changed by `update-alternatives`. It's controlled by `xdg-settings`. You can use this command to change the default from command line

```
xdg-settings set default-web-browser google-chrome.desktop
```

Comment: how about other defaults? mail/GUI editor/zip files and other file extensions.

Comment: Is your question about browsers or changing all file association?

Comment: I was using browser as an example since it was the I'm working on first. But I intend change the default for others after I'm done with browser.

Comment: This is insane.  Ubuntu left the update-alternatives method in place even though it seems to have no effect, then added the xdg-settings, and that doesn't seem to provide an easy way to get available options...?

Comment: Unfortunately, xdg-settings doesn't influence some things -- e.g. the `sensible-browser` wrapper.  Any hints on that?